# Unable to load Editor.js into LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, locker-service

I am trying to use [Editor.js](https://editorjs.io/getting-started) within an `LWC`

Editor.JS [source](https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js/releases/download/v2.23.0-rc.1/editor.js) file.

I've added the 3rd party library as a `Static Resource`

And the LWC JS file is:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import editorJS from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/EditorJS";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

export default class ExampleLWC extends LightningElement {
  isRendered = false;

  renderedCallback() {
    if (this.isRendered) {
      return;
    }

    this.isRendered = true;

    loadScript(this, editorJS)
      .then(() => {
        this.initialize();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error Loading EditorJS");
        console.log(error);  // <--- always undefined
      });
  }

  initialize() {
    console.log("Loaded EditorJS");
  }
}
```

But it fails, and the `error` variable is `undefined`

When I enabled `Debug Mode` for the user, I got more messages in the console, including:

```
Failed to load script at /resource/1641397119000/EditorJS: Cannot assign to read only property 'parseInt' of object '[object Object]'
```

**Questions**

1. Why is it not working?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Then I guess loading script is failing, cross check static resource name etc.

Comment: It's minified, and I don't have time to track it down right now, but it *appears* that it's trying to polyfill Number.parseInt, which is protected by Locker Service/Lightning Web Security. If so, that would be a reason why this code wouldn't work in LWC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_locker_comparison) offers better support for 3rd party JavaScript files. It is currently in Beta and is scheduled to be GA in the next release (Safe Harbor).

Once you [enable it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable), the EditorJS library loads perfectly.

[image]

Here is the code

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="EditorJS" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="editor" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import editorjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/editorjs';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class Hello extends LightningElement {
    isRendered = false;
    editor;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.isRendered) {
            return;
        }

        this.isRendered = true;

        loadScript(this, editorjs)
            .then(() => {
                this.initialize();
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log('Error Loading EditorJS');
            });
    }

    initialize() {
        this.editor = new EditorJS({
            holder: this.template.querySelector('.editor')
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Great work Aditya Naag, please could you share your JS code? :)

Comment: @Robs Updated the answer with code :)

Comment: Hi Aditya -  any thoughts on this [Javascript Issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/376724/unable-to-load-dhtmlx-spreadsheet-js-into-lwc)

Comment: All I had to do was enable Lightning Web Security.  ChartJS loaded fine.  PptxGenJS did not.  LWS fixed it.