# Unable to load DHTMLX Spreadsheet JS into LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, locker-service, third-party

**Background**

I am trying to use [DHTMLX Spreadsheet](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/spreadsheet/how_to_start/) in an `LWC`

I've added the `JS` and `CSS` as `Static Resources`:

- [DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_JS](https://sandbox-xhtml-developer-edition.cs119.force.com/resource/DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_JS)
- [DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_CSS](https://sandbox-xhtml-developer-edition.cs119.force.com/resource/DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_CSS)

And I have enabled `Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning Web Components`

> Setup > Session Settings > Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning Web Components

I have create an `LWC` with HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <div id="spreadsheet_container" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the `LWC` has this javascript:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_JS from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_JS";
import DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_CSS from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_CSS";

export default class Spreadsheet extends LightningElement {
    initialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.initialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.initialized = true;

        Promise.all([loadScript(this, DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_JS), loadStyle(this, DHTMLX_Spreadsheet_CSS)])
            .then(() => {
                this.initialize();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: "Error loading DHTMLX",
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: "error"
                    })
                );
            });
    }

    initialize() {   
        const container = this.template.querySelector("div.spreadsheet_container");
        const spreadsheet = new dhx.Spreadsheet(container.id, {
            toolbarBlocks: ["columns", "rows", "clear"],
            rowsCount: 10,
            colsCount: 10
        });

        const data = [
            { cell: "a1", value: "Country" },
            { cell: "b1", value: "Product" },
            { cell: "c1", value: "Price" },
            { cell: "d1", value: "Amount" },
            { cell: "e1", value: "Total Price" },

            { cell: "a2", value: "Ecuador" },
            { cell: "b2", value: "Banana" },
            { cell: "c2", value: 6.68 },
            { cell: "d2", value: 430 },
            { cell: "e2", value: 2872.4 },

            { cell: "a3", value: "Belarus" },
            { cell: "b3", value: "Apple" },
            { cell: "c3", value: 3.75 },
            { cell: "d3", value: 600 },
            { cell: "e3", value: 2250 }
        ];

        spreadsheet.parse(data);
    }
}
```

When the component loads the console log show error:

[image]

Plus the documentation says to initialise the library using line:

```
const spreadsheet = new dhx.Spreadsheet("spreadsheet", {
```

But this does not work, as we cannot access `dhx`

**Questions**

1. How can we initialise / access the `Spreadsheet` constructor?
2. What can we do about the error message appearing when the LWC loads

Comment: Hey @robs - I've taken a look, and its a problem with the library itself - It extensively uses document.body, and LWS doesn't allow elements to be appended to document.body directly - which is why you're getting this error. Due to this error, the script doesn't load, and therefore dhx is never registered on the global window object. So it looks like this library isn't supported by LWS or Locker - So VF is a better choice.